# read from the csv file for searchbox in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, intellij-idea

I want to test the e-commerce site. If you run this block of code, find the Search Box on the automation website, then type "novel" and click the button. But I want to do this using csvfiles. Csvfiles contain 1 row/column (novel). And after reading this word, he should write a novel in the search box and click the search button.

But I don't know how to read and integrate csvfiles. Could you help?

```
    public void TestSecond(){
        WebElement searchBar = driver.findElement(By.id("search-input"));
        searchBar.click();

        searchBar.sendKeys("novel");
        driver.findElement(By.className("button-search")).click();
    }
```

Comment: There are more ways how to get data from CSV file, it's pretty simple. See https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-read-csv-file-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `Scanner class` to read the CSV file. You can create a method which reads the csv files and returns the proviced value which you can use within your test method

Your solution would look like

`Method to read csv`

```
public List<String> readCsv(String path)
{ 
  List<String> novels = new ArrayList<String>();
  try 
  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(path));
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
      novels.add(scanner.next());   
    }

   } 
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
   {  
      // If required you can print the complete error trace on console   
      e.printStackTrace();
      //message indicating file was not found   
      System.out.println("File not found or is deleted");
   }
  return novels;
}
```

`Test Method`

```
 public void TestSecond(){
   List<String> novels = readCsv("path where your csv file is stored");
   for(String novel: novels)
   {
      WebElement searchBar = driver.findElement(By.id("search-input"));
      searchBar.click();

      searchBar.sendKeys(novel);
      driver.findElement(By.className("button-search")).click();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Hi @Berfin Gürz can you check the above approach

Comment: Do you know anything about "implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(45))". This is not working for my code block. Because when I was run the test, I don't see anything, everything takes too short

Comment: Hi @Berfin Gürz implicit wait is to tell the webdriver not to throw the error immediately for e.g if it doesn't find any element but to keep trying to search for the element for the specified duration before throwing the error
A detail guide for it can be found over here
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#:~:text=An%20implicit%20wait%20tells%20WebDriver,life%20of%20the%20WebDriver%20object.

Comment: Hi @Darshan If I don't want the test stages on the page to pass quickly, how should I proceed?

Comment: Hi @Berfin Gürz in case you want the test steps to slow down for you to see you can attach sleep in the steps so that the script pauses for some time after each step. Note you may use the sleep approach just to check how the script is executing but always adding the sleep for each step is not a good idea
Refer the doc for more details for the sleep command
https://tutorialsinhand.com/tutorials/selenium-python-tutorial/selenium-python-basics/time-delay-in-selenium-python.aspx. You need to add the command time.sleep(duration in seconds) at the point in each step

Comment: At the point where you want to observe the test

Comment: Updated link
https://chercher.tech/java/sleep-selenium use thread.sleep

Comment: Thank you so much for your all help. I understood now. :)